# trying to run multiple dynamic web projects on apache tomcat server in eclipse?

Tags: html, eclipse, tomcat, localhost, tomcat8

I started off by downloading Eclipse and then Tomcat 8.0, I then opened 2 dynamic web projects and I ran both of them on the Tomcat server, both under localhost8080 and they both worked fine. However I tried to then run a third dynamic web project and it would not give me the option to run it via Tomcat. I then stopped both the active servers through Eclipse so no projects were running on localhost8080 and tried again to run the third web project, but it still does not run. Sometimes when I go to 'Run As' it says none applicable, but when local tomcat server does show under 'Run As' it gives me an error (I would state what the error says but I cant get it to appear again). Any ideas at all? Thanks.

Comment: Probably its not a Web Project at all?? Please verify .. And more specific questions will be welcome..

Comment: all 3 are definitely web projects, is it true tomcat will only run 2 projects at a time?

Comment: No tomcat does not have any such limitations..I have a tomcat which is running 5 webapps..

Comment: Another guess..Maybe Your targeted runtime is not set properly..Try right clicking on your project->Properties->Targeted Runtimes->and add new or check an existing server.. Wild guess but since you can't provide the exact error maybe you could try this..